# Squid proxy performing extremely slow and sometimes doesn't work at all

Tags: performance, proxy, squid

I recently installed Squid on my desktop machine for testing purposes.
I didn't edit the config whatsoever, and just pointed firefox at the proxy to see if it was working.

Pages take an insanely long time to load, and sometimes just load forever. I don't mean for example, 10 second page loads. I mean 10 MINUTE page loads, or more.

I have Googled around and added 2 lines to my config:

```
dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8
dns_v4_first on
```

and these have not helped whatsoever.

Is there any reason this could be happening?

For reference, my desktop machine is running Arch Linux on a quad core 3Ghz i5 and 16GB of RAM.

Comment: What to the squid logs say is happening?

Comment: Logs would be helpful. Also try to `curl` the site directly from the proxy server and see if it also takes a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this on my own after a bunch more research.
I had a rewrite script set that I forgot I set, and said script was crashing on 90% of URLs. Fixing the script fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This still might be IPv6 : 
[Squid will still perform both IPv6 and IPv4 DNS lookups before connecting.](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/dns_v4_first/)

Make sure there is no IPv6 line in `/etc/hosts` and is disabled on your host.

Comment: This is not an ipv6 issue. My desktop machine has full ipv6 connectivity to the Internet.

Comment: Alright, then I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following line to your config file, it will stop IPv6 which slowed down my squid connections.

```
tcp_outgoing_address 0.0.0.0 all
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my OpenSUSE from Leap 15.2 to 15.3 and had squid being very slow afterwards. Found that it was an issue with NS resolution, as upgrade had replaced my /etc/resolv.conf with a link to an empty default file, so nameserver was not found.

Should check this if you encounter similar problems.
(Could also be solved with dns_nameservers setting for squid, but bad resolv.conf will cause other problems as well ...)